# Python Networkx: preserving nodes ID when saving/serializing networks to hardisk

Tags: python, serialization, pickle, networkx, gml

I am using networkx1.10 in Python for a project that requires to dump the networks on the hardisk and later reload them in order to continue a the execution of some algorithm that manipulates such networks.

I've been trying doing that in a couple of different ways: using nx.write_gml() and nx_read_gml() at first, now with pickle/cpickle.

Although superficially everything seems working fine, I've noticed that I get different results in my simulation whether the saving/loading happens or not at some point in time.

I think this might be related to the fact that some networks seem to be  modified by the dumping/reloading procedure (which is of course unexpected).

For debugging, now I am saving and reloading each network with pickle, comparing their gml representation (achieved with nx.write_gml / nx.generate_gml) before and after dumping/reloading. Doing so, I've noticed some discrepancies.

In some cases it's just the order of some of the graph attributes that gets modified, with causes no harm in my program. In other cases, the order in which two edges appear in the gml representation is different, again no harm.

Often, however, the ID of some nodes is modified, as in this example:

https://www.diffchecker.com/zvzxrshy

Although the edges seem to be modified accordingly so that the network appears to be equivalent, this change in the ID can alter my simulation (for reasons that I am not going to explain).

I believe this might be the root of my problems.

Do you know why this is happening, even when using a low level serialization mechanism such as those implemented by pickle/cpickle?

How can I ensure that the networks are exactly the same before and after the serialization procedure?

I am doing something like this:

```
with open('my_network.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(my_network, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
...
with open('my_network.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
    my_network_reloaded = pickle.load(handle)

# compare nx.write_gml for my_network and my_network_reloaded
```

Any help will be highly appreciated: I've been fighting with this issue for the last three days and I am going crazy!

Thank you

Comment: I can't really tell from the docs, but is there any difference between using Python's `pickle` and `write_gpickle` and `read_gpickle` ([description](https://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/readwrite.gpickle.html))?

Comment: I had problems using both...

Comment: The crux of your question is " (for reasons that I am not going to explain)".  If you really need to generate gml format output with specific id and ordering you'll need to modify the existing writer or write some custom software do that.  Could you use other attributes than id to mark your nodes?  (For gml format those need to be integers and are generated automatically to ensure that).

Comment: @Aric the reason why I think these changes in node IDs when serializing networks might be the root of my problems is that my algorithm does manipulate the networks in a way that might be sensitive to those changes. From time to time I randomly select nodes (and edges) like this: random.choice(G.nodes()), and perform some operation on that node/edge (e.g. modify an attribute, remove the node, add an edge, etc.). I fear that if the ordering/id of nodes change, I might end up selecting different nodes than those I would select otherwise, and, as a consequence, I alter the overall results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They seem to be the same graphs, up to isomorphism.

Your issue may be node order. Indeed, networkx uses dicts to store nodes and edges, which are unordered and randomized.

You have two solutions: either ignore that, or use ordered graphs:

```
>>> class OrderedGraph(nx.Graph):
...    node_dict_factory = OrderedDict
...    adjlist_dict_factory = OrderedDict
>>> G = OrderedGraph()
>>> G.add_nodes_from( (2,1) )
>>> G.nodes()
[2, 1]
>>> G.add_edges_from( ((2,2), (2,1), (1,1)) )
>>> G.edges()
[(2, 2), (2, 1), (1, 1)]
```

(example from [the documentation of the Graph class](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/classes.graph.html))

Comment: I am starting to think you might be right, I'll test this. Still, I don't understand why something like that might happen between pickle calls. I might expect additional networkx operations to alter the order, but not pickle. Maybe it restores the object differently in memory, and networkx somehow restructures the graph accordingly? Do you think that manually sorting an unsorted graph (using [topological_sort](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.topological_sort.html?highlight=sort) might work too?

Comment: Pickling stores the content, not the exact memory layout of the data structure, which is randomized on purpose. And `topological_sort` does not sort the graph (its data structures are inherently non-ordered, anyway), but returns a list of nodes without changing the graph.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Well, tomorrow I am gonna try first assigning ID explicitly, with the hope that reading/writing functions won't mess up with those (I've read that they are managed internally only if not specified). If this doesn't work I will try your solution. I will keep you guys posted.

Comment: You are going to need to modify the writer in gml.py if you want some special order.  The ids are generated at run-time according to the ordering in list(G).

Comment: @ValentinLorentz I tried your OrderedGraph solution, but I get an error at this line: nx.simple_cycles(G)

  File "mytest.py", line 2685, in hasCycles
    return sum(1 for e in nx.simple_cycles(G)) != 0
  File "<decorator-gen-90>", line 2, in simple_cycles
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx/utils/decorators.py", line 66, in _not_implemented_for
    ' '.join(graph_types))

Looks like my graph is no more directed. In fact, how do we say that we still want a directed graph? I tried changing OrderedGraph(nx.Graph) in class OrderedGraph(nx.DiGraph), with no result

Comment: @Aric Can you be more specific please? Thank you

Comment: @Kilin My example was for undirected graphs. For directed graphs, inherit from `nx.DiGraph` instead of `nx.Graph`.

Comment: @ValentinLorentz yeah,I figured that out, but I was doing another silly mistake and I could not see the effect of this change. Now it's running, let's see if that solves the problem...

Comment: @ValentinLorentz the solution based on OrderedGraph seems to be working! It needs some testing, but it seems ok. Thank you so much!!!